# Socket programming: notify all clients before shutting server down

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I'm trying to implement a server (with ability to accept multiple clients) and a client using [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) tutorial and making some extensions.
Everything works fine except for one feature:
when the server has been running for 1 minute, it shuts down and each client has to print the message 'server shutting down' and close.

in my analog to [KKMultiServer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KKMultiServer.java) I implement it this way, in the main method:

```
long in1minute = 10*1000;
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule( new TimerTask(){
              public void run() {
                  for(int i=0;i<startedThreads.size();i++){
                      try {
                        startedThreads.get(i).Close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  }

                  listening=false;
               }
         },  in1minute );
```

while each started thread was added to the vector.

in my analog to the [KKMultiServerThread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KKMultiServerThread.java) this code should send the message to the clients (my analog to [KKProtocol](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KnockKnockProtocol.java) proceeds it correctly)

```
public void Close() throws IOException{
    String outputLine=p.processInput("shut");
    out.println(outputLine);
    out.close();
    in.close();
    socket.close();
}
```

The Server stops normally, but the clients do not print the message 'server shutting down'. Then, if I invoke the client when server is  shut, I get:

```
     [java] Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection rese
tClient: d
     [java]     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
     [java]     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
     [java]     at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
     [java]     at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
     [java]     at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
     [java]     at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
     [java]     at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
     [java]     at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
     [java]     at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
     [java]     at ist.assignment2.Client.main(Client.java:31)
     [java]
```

Code for `Client.java:31`

```
 while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
```

...and then analog to [KKClient](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KnockKnockClient.java)

So why don't the clients print the message and exit?

Comment: Is there anything else that closes the sockets? NB you don't need `in.close()`, and `socket.close()` should be in a finally block. What's the purpose of this protocol? Wouldn't it be better to have a 1-minute read timeout *per client*, and if it fires *then* send the shutdown message and close *that client?*

Comment: @EJP no, I posted everything relevant. the protocol generates correct server output according to the client input. Well its rather about implementing an idea I had now, than implementing some optimal concept. and I just want to understand why it doesn't work. I'm a bit confused with the  while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) loop. How does it actually starts to read each input at the needed time and when will it exit?

Comment: `readLine()` blocks until a complete line or an EOS is received.

Comment: @EJP why doesnt the loop exit when there is no line (immidiately if client is not sending anything)? does the loop just freeze until then? how come?

Answer (score 3):

A TCP socket should not be closed, if the other side hasn't acknowledged all data. This mechanism is designed into most application protocols. For example with HTTP, SMTP, IMAP, POP3, the server signals when the connection should be closed, the client closes the socket and afterwards the server closes the socket.

In your case, you can extend your `Close` method as follows:

```
public void Close() throws IOException {
    String outputLine = p.processInput("shut");
    out.println(outputLine);
    // signal the client that the connection should be closed
    socket.shutdownOutput();
    // wait on ack by blocking until EOF is received
    if (in.read() != -1) {
       throw new RuntimeException("unexpected data sent by client");
    }
    // close socket
    socket.close();
}
```

Comment: hm, now something totally weird is happening. when the timer passes 1 minute nothing happens, clients and server are still working. then the server will process the 1 command, and if I send the 2nd command the client stops successfully (but withoud the message "server shutting down"), server throws the runtime exception you wrote and continues running oO

Comment: @IAM Can you post a complete and minimal example that shows the problem. I suppose there are other issues that cause this problem, e.g. bad thread synchronization.